# Confused by 'up-to-date' message in git workflow

Tags: git

Why does git say local master is up to date with origin/master when I can pull an update?

```
[rails-app (dev)]$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
[rails-app (master)]$ git pull origin master
remote: Counting objects: 13, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
remote: Total 13 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (13/13), done.
From bitbucket.org:account-name/rails-app
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   2f2fcc0..b3e3bed  master     -> origin/master
Updating 2f2fcc0..b3e3bed
Fast-forward
 app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss | 7 -------
 app/mailers/reminder_mailer.rb          | 2 ++
 config/routes.rb                        | 2 --
 3 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 9 deletions(-)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `origin/master` is the "last known state" of the remote, not necessarily the current state of the remote. If you did `git fetch` first and then `git status`, you would see a message indicating that you are behind `origin/master`.