# git checkout to another branch cannot show its correct status

Tags: git, github

I have 2 computers and made some code changes in one computer, then push to the GitHub. From another computer, I ran `git checkout master` and got the information like 'your branch is up-to-date'. In fact, there should have some changes, the status should be like the following:

```
> git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
(use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

When I ran `git pull`, I can get many files update. e.g. I attached the screenshot.

So, I don't know what the problem is. Is it caused by my git config or something else?

[image]

However, when I used the 3rd computer, and checkout to master branch, it terminal prompt to me there are new commits, I need to update. e.g.

[image]

Comment: It should be up-to-date with `origin/master`, before you do any `git-pull` or `git-fetch`. Yes, you did push some new changes to the remote repository. But, the other computer's repository does not know about the new changes yet. Its `origin/master` was updated by the last `git-pull` or `git-fetch`. It will be updated to know about the new changes after you do another `git-pull` or `git-fetch`. `origin/master` is a remote tracking branch in name only. It is a local branch.

Comment: @ElpieKay, what you said is making sense. But the fact is different. I tried another computer and uploaded the screenshot. You can see that when I 'git checkout master', the output is different, the message and the terminal can prompt to me that I need to run `git pull` to get new commits.

Comment: `git fetch` (pull does a fetch) will update the entire state of the remote. If you pull on one branch and change to an outdated one, you'll be notified because the first pull fetched the state for the other branch’s upstream too (without updating that local branch). Before that happens, the local repository has no way of knowing things changed on the remote.

Comment: Repositories are independent of each other. You sync histories you care about with other repositories using `git push` and `git fetch` and various specific-workflow-convenience commands that invoke those as part of some handy recipe for you.  (edit: this is pretty much what Ryan said, just a slightly different point of view on it).

Comment: @Orionpax The relationship between `master` and `origin/master`, whether `master` is behind, ahead of, or up-to-date with `origin/master`, has nothing to do with the master in the github repository. If you run `git merge origin/master`, then `git status` tells you it's up-to-date. If you run `git reset HEAD~5 --hard`, then it tells it's behind `origin/master`. If you make some new commits, then it tells it's ahead of `origin/master`.

Comment: @Orionpax It says `Use "git pull" to update your local branch"` just because `master` is behind `origin/master`, not because the master branch in the github repository has new commits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused by 'up-to-date' message in git workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869483/confused-by-up-to-date-message-in-git-workflow)