# Why does git status return different results on different branches?

Tags: git

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: Z746
```

`git status` in `master` tells me that my working tree is clean and my branch is up-to-date with the origin (`origin/master`). However, when I `git pull`, it pulls down a whole bunch of new code that I didn't yet have.

```
$ git status
On branch development
Your branch is behind 'origin/development' by 243 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
(use "git pull" to update your local branch)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$
```

`git status` on the `development` branch tells me that my working tree is clean but my branch is behind the origin (`origin/development`). So I git pull and it pulls down a whole bunch of new code that I didn't yet have.

My question is this: Why does the same command `git status` sometimes tell me I need to pull code and sometimes it doesn't?
Is it to do with the branch that I'm on? Changing branches? What?

Comment: Until you `pull` (or `fetch`), it only knows what has changed *locally* since the last time you synced with `origin/master`.

Comment: just run `git fetch` before `git status`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused by 'up-to-date' message in git workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869483/confused-by-up-to-date-message-in-git-workflow)

Comment: Please do not post [screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste it directly into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case contents of your local checkout of `master` branch are compared to the latest known version of remote tracking branch stored in `origin/master`. Since no network operation is performed at this stage and your checkout seems up to date that's what reported. Now, once you issue `git pull` you order it to contact the remote repository and, if there are any new changes, apply them to your local copy.

In the second case you checked out branch `development`, switched to another branch, issued `git pull` (which updates only checked out branch) or `git fetch` (which doesn't update the current branch). Now when you issue `git status` git realizes that your local checkout is behind the remote counterpart. Issuing `git pull` will update the local branch to the latest revision available in remote repo.